# Mysql query: group by add extra column of return records but not affected group by function

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this query, with record same age and power, expect to get record with lower age.

**Query 1:**

```
select w.id, wp.age , min(w.coins_needed), w.power
from wands w
join wands_property wp
on w.code = wp.code
where wp.is_evil = 0 
group by wp.age, w.power,w.coins_needed, w.id
order by w.power desc, wp.age desc
```

1303 496 6678 10 
1038 496 4789 10 
1130 494 9439 10 
1315 492 4126 10 
892 492 4345 10 
9 491 7345 10 
858 483 4352 10 
--have more--

**Query 2:**

```
select wp.age , min(w.coins_needed), w.power
from wands w
join wands_property wp
on w.code = wp.code
where wp.is_evil = 0 
group by wp.age, w.power
order by w.power desc, wp.age desc
```

496 4789 10 
494 9439 10 
492 4126 10 
491 7345 10 
483 4352 10 
481 9831 10 
464 4952 10 
--have more--

As you can see in query 1 result, have duplicated age-power (row 1,2 and row 4,5...). It cause wrong result but i need exactly all 4 filed id, age, min(w.coins_needed), w.power

In query 2 result, it work as expected but don't have id field.

Have any way to add id field but not use subquery in this situation? Thanks.